# When saving to a file is there a way to not override whats already in the file?

Tags: c++

When saving something to a text file is there a way to not override whats in the file already?

EX.

**blah.txt**

this is an example

```
fout << "of saving to a file.";
```

i want the "of saving to a file" to be added on to "this is an example" not to override it.

Comment: Look at the options to the open call - there should be an append mode.

Comment: you have to set opening mode flag to ate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the append flag, like this:

```
fstream fout("blah.txt", ios::app);
```

if you are opening it after declaration, use something like this:

```
fout.open("blash.txt", fstream::app);
```

Comment: Plan on it. Have to wait 5mins

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file with the appropriate write mode in order to *append* to it instead of overwriting:

```
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","a");
```

[(C style)](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/), or

```
fstream filestr ("myfile.txt", fstream::ate | fstream::out);
```

[(C++ style)](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/fstream/). In the latter case, you may want to use `fstream::app` instead of `fstream::ate` - this sets the file pointer to the end of the file before each output operation.

Comment: so instead of using fout.open(blah.txt) what should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to open the file in [append mode](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/).

```
ofstream fout("blah.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file output stream in append mode:

```
ofstream fout(<path>, ios::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the write position if you want to

u need: 
      `#include <stdio.h>`
    ...

```
FILE *file = fopen("my_file.txt", "w");
fputs ("This is some text." , file);
fseek (file , 15, SEEK_SET);
fputs (" sam" ,file);
fclose (file);
```